# How do I fix the error on my domain name (promining.digital)?

Tags: wordpress, dns, namecheap

I tried installing wordpress on my domain name and while doing so, I changed the directory from http//: to https//: not knowing that ssl has not finished installing. So the website crashed, then I attached some codes to my wp-config.php file and functions.php file in the file manager. Now if I try to enter my domain, it will show me (This domain is registered at namecheap and that I should check back later). It has been like this for two days now and I do not know what to do.
[Attached is a screenshot of how my domain opens if I open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K04K8.png)

Comment: It's like the "namecheap div" is already present in your header file ..try to remove that !

Comment: Thank you for your help. I contacted my hosting customer service and they fixed it for me from their end.